# Drag and Drop into Favourite Tags - Adds URL as a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Possible bug?

(Using firefox on Mac, on Serverfault)

I dragged a tag from the right hand side into the favourite tags box, and then clicked add.

What I got was an added tag such as: 'https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dns'

Perhaps the DnD functionality should ensure only the last part gets added as a tag?

---

Update: Based on random's clarification, rather than fixing the DnD, should just fix the onclick for the Add button?

Comment: Also does it in Chrome on XP.

Comment: Apologies for having posted this originally on serverfault rather than meta. I thought I had :-) and wondered if I'd gone mad when I was looking for my posting....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no drag-and-drop functionality with the tags right now.

What you did, and can do on most browsers, is just grab the URL of the thing and it will perform a paste right into whatever input you're going for.

You can also do what you did with avatars or links. But it doesn't mean it's drag-and-drop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my update.